# Visualise results of numerical optimization

Tags: r

I would like to visualise the solution to a linear programming problem using  R program.

Here is the problem:
  (use graphical method to maximize `Z = 40X + 20Y` subject to `3x + 2y <= 300, 2x + 4y <= 450, 5x + 7y <= 560`

---

After solving the problem using the following code

```
library(lpSolve) 

obj <- c(40,20) 
con.mat <- matrix(c(3,2,2,4,5,7),nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) 
con.dir <- c("<=") 
con.val <- c(300,450,560)

oursolution <- lp("max",obj,con.mat,con.dir,con.val)
```

I need help in making a plot to visualize my solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "using a graphical method"? Do you want to plot something and then read off values from the plot? There are functions that solve a linear programming problem numerically. An what is not going through? Have you tried something and gotten out error messages? If so, post the code and the error messages.

Comment: after solving the problem in R using the following codelibrary(lpSolve)
obj<-c(40,20)
con.mat<-matrix(c(3,2,2,4,5,7),nrow=3,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
con.mat
con.dir<-c("<=")
con.dir
con.val<-c(300,450,560)
con.val
oursolution<-lp("max",obj,con.mat,con.dir,con.val,maximum=TRUE)
oursolution.........i was required to plot a graph in R showing the required region

Comment: Add that code to your question and explain clearly what you want. It seems you already solved the optimisation problem numerically. What you want (probably) is thus not to solve the problem graphically, but rather make a plot to visualise your solution. This is not the same thing.

Comment: thankyou stibu..my challenge is in making a plot  to visualize my solution

Comment: @mutuku; i have added your code from the comments to the question, and changed the wording slightly. Can you check that it is what you intend,  the example is self-contained and that it runs as expected. Thanks